# Querying Related Account IDs Linked to a Public Key in Hedera Hashgraph

Tags: public-key, cryptocurrency, hedera-hashgraph

I'm exploring Hedera Hashgraph and aiming to retrieve all associated account IDs linked to a specific public key within the network.

Could someone guide me on the best approach or the relevant API calls and processes required to extract all related account IDs associated with a given public key in Hedera Hashgraph? Any code examples or detailed steps would be highly appreciated.

I've researched various approaches and API functionalities but haven't found a definitive method to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6):

I've found the API endpoint below, which is functional. However, I'm still exploring for a better solution using the Hedera Hashgraph Node.js SDK:

https://mainnet-public.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/accounts?account.publickey=302a300506032b...

Comment: This is currently not possible with the SDK, because the HAPIs currently do not include an implementation for key based query. Therefore, using the mirror node APIs, as you have, is indeed the correct (and only) way to do accomplish this.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk IMHO, the link above isn't merely a link to an external resource, but also demonstrates a correct solution, which happens to be a simply API request.
I believe this qualifies according to the S/O community consensus, see the top answer on your linked question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226142/138717
"Answers need to have sufficient information to understand the answer. The answer should be described in a reasonable level of detail and / or include a minimal example of the answer."

Comment: @sina Nonetheless, I recommend that you may improve your answer by including another link to the canonical reference for this particular mirror node API, which is it's interactive swagger doc: https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/docs/#/accounts/listAccounts